# Wordpress query posts on meta values

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble with a custom search script which looks at Meta values associated with posts.

```
 <?php
 $gender = $_POST['gender'];
 $eyes = $_POST['eyes'];

 if ($eyes == "{empty}") {$eyes = "%%";} 
 if (($gender == "either") || (empty($gender))) {$gender ="%%";}
 $args = array(
 'meta_query'=> array(
 array(
 'key'=>"Eyes",
 'value'=> "$eyes",
 ),
 array(
 'key' => "Gender",
 'value'=> "$gender",
 )
 ));
 query_posts($args);
 ?>
```

I only have one post at the moment, which is Gender-Female and Eyes-Green.

If the variables are set as Female, Green it will show the post. However if Gender is set as either or is left empty it will not work. It seems like my wildcards are not working.

I have tried to do this so many different ways and having no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `{empty}` for eyes but `empty()` for gender?  Have you checked the values of both `$eyes` and `$gender` to be sure their values are correct?

Comment: eyes is a drop down, with the first option "Please select" with a value of {empty}

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
array( 
 'key'=>"Eyes",
 'value'=> "$eyes",
 ),
```

With

```
array(array( 
 'key'=>"Eyes",
 'value'=> "$eyes",
 )),
```